# Emacs background is grey after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, emacs

I use Emacs within Terminal on my MacBook.  I have configured Emacs to use the color-theme package.  I prefer the "whateveryouwant" theme, which has a white background.  Incidentally, I also have a white background in my Terminal sessions.

Now, after upgrading to Snow Leopard, my Emacs background is grey.  This is annoying.

I'm running GNU Emacs 22.3.1.

How can I make my Emacs background white?

### More info

The emacs background is white if I start with emacs with 'emacs -q'.  When I have an .emacs that only contains this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/")
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-whateveryouwant)
```

the background becomes grey.

I tried recompiling the latest version of color-theme by typing 'make', and I get this error message:

http://pastebin.com/f71b6bec4

Any idea why?  Seems to be that installing Snow Leopard installed a new emacs, which doesn't like color theme?

### Even more info

I still have not fixed the grey background.  I did fix the compile errors with these changes:

```
diff --git a/color-theme/themes/color-theme-example.el b/color-theme/themes/color-theme-example.el
index f73b4f6..1961a01 100644
--- a/color-theme/themes/color-theme-example.el
+++ b/color-theme/themes/color-theme-example.el
@@ -1,4 +1,5 @@
 (eval-when-compile
+  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/")
   (require 'color-theme))

 (defun color-theme-example ()
diff --git a/color-theme/themes/color-theme-library.el b/color-theme/themes/color-theme-library.el
index d194708..edc7d94 100644
--- a/color-theme/themes/color-theme-library.el
+++ b/color-theme/themes/color-theme-library.el
@@ -28,6 +28,7 @@

 ;; Code:
 (eval-when-compile
+  (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/")
   (require 'color-theme))

 (defun color-theme-gnome ()
```

Unfortunately, I still get a grey background instead of white whenever color-theme is initialized.

Comment: what do you get as result when running `M-: (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode)`? It should be "light" and not "dark" if your background is white.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjusting the background value of the default face from "white" to "gray00" fix the issue.

You could adjust the color-theme-library.el, but I prefer to suggest to adjust your .emacs.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/color-theme/")
(require 'color-theme)
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-whateveryouwant)
;
; Force background color to white for Snow Leopard
; TODO: revisit this fix when the reason why the background
; was gray is identified.
;
(custom-set-faces
 '(default ((t (:stipple nil :background "gray00" :foreground "black"
:inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil
:slant normal :weight normal :height 1 :width normal :family "default")))))
```

You could achieve a simular result by using *M-x customize > Faces > Basic Faces > Default Face* and setting Background to "gray00".

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I hope the color-theme library is adjusted once the reason is identified, but for now this is excellent.  I finally have my white background back!

Comment: I'm not sure that the color-theme library need to be adjusted. I really try to identify the reason of that strange behaviour. We could assume that gray00 == white... so I suppose there is something else that interferes with the color-theme... Anyway, the goal was to make it work asap.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "white"))
```

Comment: This didn't help.

Comment: Curious.  Have you tried `emacs -q` to see if the problem is in your .emacs?

Comment: ah yes, i'll edit my question.

Comment: Note: for me, `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(background-color . "gray00"))` finally solved the problem. None of the above worked except for going to `customize > Faces ...` every single darn time

Answer (score 1):

Emacs is looking for

```
themes/color-theme-example.elc
```

but your theme example was written as

```
/Users/gharfst/.emacs.d/color-theme/color-theme.elc
```

Try this in your init.el:

```
(setq color-theme-directory "/Users/gharfst/.emacs.d/color-theme")
```

Comment: This didn't solve my grey background, but it helped me solve the compile errors.  I'll edit my question with the new info.

Answer (score 0):

Hit `M-x customize` then go to "`faces`" and then "`basic faces`". There you can alter the default face. The foreground and background settings are the ones you want to look at.

Comment: I browsed through customize, as you suggested.  I see that the background is white.  I see "[X] Background: white      (sample)".  Unfortunately, on the screen, the background is grey.

Answer (score 0):

Can't find documentation to support my theory, but I think Emacs is just adding the shading to stand out from the white background in Terminal. Or vice versa.
I suppose you could try changing your Terminal background to Grey to see?

Comment: Nope -- I changed the background to black, and the emacs background is still grey.